# How do I read a file with ReadFile onto the stack in NASM x86 assembly?

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86, nasm

I have opened a file with OpenFile, and gotten its size with GetFileSize. I wish to use ReadFile and use the stack as the buffer it requires, allocating enough room on the stack with the size of the file returned from GetFileSize. When I run this I get no output.

Here is my code...

```
extern GetStdHandle
extern GetModuleFileNameA
extern OpenFile
extern ReadFile
extern WriteFile
extern CloseHandle
extern GetFileSize
extern ExitProcess

import GetStdHandle kernel32.dll
import GetModuleFileNameA kernel32.dll
import OpenFile kernel32.dll
import ReadFile kernel32.dll
import WriteFile kernel32.dll
import CloseHandle kernel32.dll
import GetFileSize kernel32.dll
import ExitProcess kernel32.dll

global ..start

segment .code USE32

..start:

;Setting up the stack...
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

;Get standard output to console
push dword -11
call [GetStdHandle]
mov dword [hStdOut], eax

;Get filepath...
push dword filepath
push dword 0
call [GetModuleFileNameA]

;Outputting filepath
;Doesn't show up on the console but if you dump it to a file
;and edit it it is there...
;push dword 0
;push dword bytesRead
;push dword 128 ;Maximum path size for OpenFile...
;push dword filepath
;push dword [hStdOut]
;call [WriteFile]

;Opening the file and getting the handle...
push dword 0
push dword ofstruct
push dword filepath
mov dword [hSelfFile]

;Getting the file size...
push dword 0
push dword hSelfFile
call [GetFileSize]
mov dword [fSize], eax

;Allocating data on the stack...
sub esp, fSize

;Reading the file...
push dword 0
push dword bytesRead
push dword fSize
push dword ebp ;ebp or esp?
push dword [hSelfFile]
call [ReadFile]

;Outputting the read file...
push dword 0
push dword bytesRead
push dword fSize
push dword ebp ;ebp or esp?
push dword [hStdOut]
call [WriteFile]

;Closing the file handle...
push dword hSelfFile
call [CloseHandle]

;Cleaning up the stack...
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp

xor eax, eax
push eax
call [ExitProcess]

segment .data

segment .bss

hStdOut resd 1
hSelfFile resd 1
bytesRead resd 1
ofstruct resb 136 ;The size in bytes of ofstruct
fSize resd 1
filepath resb 128 ;Maximum path OpenFile will allow
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What debugging have you done? It's not at all clear that your code checks return values for errors.

Comment: Your code is missing parts, copy-paste error? `mov dword [hSelfFile]` doesn't make sense, and you are probably missing a `call [OpenFile]` too. PS: Learn to use a debugger. Also, for the `GetFileSize` you probably want `push dword [hSelfFile]` not `push dword hSelfFile`.

Comment: You should push the value of ESP after you subtracted from from it, instead of EBP. That means you need to save that value before you do more push parameters because that changes ESP. Subtracting from ESP doesn't change EBP. ESP points to the top of the stack (the lowest valid address on the stack), so the buffer you allocated by subtracting from ESP is that the top of the stack where ESP is pointing to. However its not as simple as that. Your code may fail if the size of file greater than 4096 bytes (the size of a virtual memory page).

Comment: Is there any way to get around the paging problem? Other programs don't seem to have a problem loading large files into memory.

Comment: You shouldn't load large files into the stack. Allocate heap memory.

Comment: I'll take a read... What I really want is to be able to find the file size and read that many bytes out of the file, so it's dynamic in a sense.

Comment: Shouldn't I just use malloc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

malloc?  Why would you link to the C library when there are memory functions that are part of Windows?

Besides all of the mistakes in your code, you do realize that you are trying to open an executable file and print the contents to the console?  You cannot do that (well you can but you won't get anything pretty) since exes contain non printable characters, you will see a lot of garbage on the screen.

Here is some example code that will open a text file in the exes directory, get the size, allocate some memory to hold file, read file, and display the contents to the console.

There is absolutely no error checking involved here, you would of course add error checking in a normal app.

Create a text file called test.txt and save it in the exes directory.  You can fill this file with whatever text you want for this test.  I chose to use a bacon lorem ipsum generator, since I like bacon :-)

```
%define STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE -11
%define OPEN_EXISTING 3
%define NULL 0
%define HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY 8
%define FILE_READ_DATA 1

;%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
section .bss
hConOut         resd 1
lpBytesWritten  resd 1
hSelfFile       resd 1
hHeap           resd 1
lpFileSize      resd 1
hReadBuf        resd 1

;%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
section .data
szTestFile      db 'test.txt', 0
szCRLF          db 13, 10 

;%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
global Start
section .text
Start:    
    call    GetProcessHeap                  ; get handle to apps heap
    mov     [hHeap], eax        

    push    STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE               ; um, self explanitory
    call    GetStdHandle
    mov     [hConOut], eax

    push    NULL
    push    NULL
    push    OPEN_EXISTING
    push    NULL
    push    0
    push    FILE_READ_DATA
    push    szTestFile
    call    CreateFileA                     ; Let's open the damn file
    mov     [hSelfFile], eax   

    push    NULL
    push    eax
    call    GetFileSize                     ; well, get the size of file to read
    add     eax, 1
    mov     [lpFileSize], eax

    push    eax
    push    HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY
    push    dword [hHeap]
    call    HeapAlloc                       ; now allocate some memory to hold contents
    mov     [hReadBuf], eax

    push    NULL
    push    lpBytesWritten
    push    dword [lpFileSize]
    push    dword [hReadBuf]
    push    dword [hSelfFile]
    call    ReadFile                        ; slurp it into memory

    push    dword [hSelfFile]
    call    CloseHandle                     ; don't need anymore

    push    NULL
    push    lpBytesWritten 
    push    dword [lpFileSize]
    push    dword [hReadBuf]
    push    dword [hConOut]
    call    WriteFile                       ; print to console

    push    NULL
    push    lpBytesWritten 
    push    2
    push    szCRLF                          
    push    dword [hConOut]
    call    WriteFile                       ; "display carrage return/linefeed"

    push    NULL
    push    hReadBuf
    call    HeapFree                        ; free the our buffer memory

    push    0
    call    ExitProcess

;%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
extern GetStdHandle
extern CreateFileA
extern ReadFile
extern WriteFile
extern CloseHandle
extern GetFileSize
extern ExitProcess
extern GetProcessHeap
extern HeapAlloc
extern HeapFree
```

Comment: Simplistic, clean code, and very informative. Although I am a big fan of learning on your own, this is a steer in the right direction, I can't wait to adopt this code and play with it. Nifty how you put the .text section last...